# Write a list having string and dictionary to a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a list having string in the first element of a list and a dictionary in the second element which has some flags and associated counts with it, how can i write it to a csv file in python?

list is as follows

```
['(RenderThread)', 
  Counter({'flags=4': 752, 'flags=40': 299, 'flags=10004': 283,
           'flags=80': 203, 'flags=90002': 36, 'flags=10080': 31, 
           'flags=100': 23, 'flags=10040': 14, 'flags=10100': 9})]
<type 'list'>
```

I want output as follows

```
RenderThread    flags=100   flags=10004 flags=10040 flags=10080 flags=10100 flags=4 flags=40    flags=80    flags=90002
                      23            283          14          31           9     752      299        203             36
```

here is my code snippet

```
with open(outputcsv,'wb') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv,delimiter=',')
    for x in threads:
        writer.writerows([x.split(',')])
        w = csv.DictWriter(outcsv,data1)
        w.writerow(counter1)
        writer.writerows('\n')
```

where data1 = [thr1,counter1]

Comment: The second element is a thing called `Counter` ... what's that?

Comment: You say `for x in threads` ... but you only show one list. Is the list you show just one item in an outer list?

Comment: Counter is counting the number of occurences of flags in an event

Comment: for now i'm working with a single list, i'll be expanding it to all threads, once i resolve how to get this done

Comment: the output shown is basically a snapshot of how data looks in a csv file, so to make it similar i've added much spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a guess about what your data looks like, but I think you can combine the two items in the list into a single dict and then just use `DictWriter` to write the whole thing. There are several oddities, including my guess about what your data list looks like and that you want comma separators even though you show a bunch of space padding in your output. Working examples can really help sort some of these questions out.

```
import csv

# example input
data = ['(RenderThread)', {'flags=4': 752, 'flags=40': 299}]

# presumably its one of many in an outer list
threads = [data]

def render_thread_iter(threads):
    """Given an interator that emits [RenderThread, FlagsDict] lists,
    iterate dicts where render thread is added to flags dict.
    """
    for data in threads:
        d = {'RenderThread':data[0]}
        d.update(data[1])
        yield d

with open('output.csv','w', newline='') as outcsv:
    # create list of header fields
    fieldnames = ['RenderThread'] + sorted(threads[0][1].keys())
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outcsv, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    # write rendered dicts
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(render_thread_iter(threads))
```